# Had Frank Herbert planned out the Dune series when he wrote the first book?

Tags: dune

One of the great things about *Dune* is the way it works well as a standalone story with a satisfactory ending that, while leaving room open for more, gives a sense of completion to the story.

When he wrote it, did Frank Herbert plan for *Dune* to be a standalone story, or was it always meant to be part of a wider series with notes and chapters meant for *Dune* being saved for a future book and a clear multi book arc defined for his main characters in the same way as Robert Jordan, JK Rowling or Brandon Sanderson did/do?

Comment: I believe I remember it being mentioned in other questions that Dune, Dune Messiah and Children of Dune were originally intended to be one book.  But no idea if he had pre-planned any of the rest to any degree.

Comment: Something that counts against the books originally being conceived as a series is the time between the books: Dune (1965), Dune Messiah (1969), Children of Dune (1976), God-Emperor (1981). Heretics and Chapterhouse came out within a year of each other and were probably conceived as a whole (with an intended third book).

Comment: Although this is very late, for what it’s worth Brian Herbert wrote out the books beyond the sixth based on notes Frank Herbert left behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was always meant to be a wider series.  From Frank Herbert's forward in *Heretics of Dune*:

> Parts of Dune Messiah and Children of Dune were written before Dune
> was completed. They fleshed out more in the writing, but the essential
> story remained intact. I was a writer and I was writing.